# Save Checkbox Value from jTable into database

Tags: mysql, database, swing, jtable

I want to save the content of my jTable into Mysql Database. I managed to save the student name,gender,id into database but I don't know how to save the checkbox value.The checkbox function as tool to determine whether a student is absent/present. How could I do this?

[image]

This is the code I used to add checkbox in JTable.

```
   private Map<Integer, Boolean> checkBoxes = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

private TableModel model;
private String columnName;

public CheckBoxWrapperTableModel(TableModel model, String columnName)
{
    this.model = model;
    this.columnName = columnName;
}

  @Override
public String getColumnName(int col)
{
 int column=0;
    return (column > 0) ? model.getColumnName(col - 1) : columnName;
}
   @Override
public int getRowCount()
{
    return model.getRowCount();
}
   @Override
public int getColumnCount()
{
    return model.getColumnCount() + 1;
}
    @Override

public Object getValueAt(int row, int col)
{
    if (col > 0)
        return model.getValueAt(row, col - 1);

    else
    {
        Object value = checkBoxes.get(row);
        return (value == null) ? Boolean.FALSE : value;
    }
}
   @Override

public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
{
    if (col > 0)
        return model.isCellEditable(row, col - 1);
    else
        return true;
}
   @Override
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col)
{
    if (col > 0)
        model.setValueAt(value, row, col - 1);
    else
        checkBoxes.put(row, (Boolean) value);

    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
   @Override
public Class getColumnClass(int col)
{
    return (col > 0) ? model.getColumnClass(col - 1) : Boolean.class;
}
}
```

This is my Save Button code:

```
       try{   

      String sql = "insert into attendance.status values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
      int row = Attendance.getSelectedRow();
      pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setObject(1,Attendance.getModel().getValueAt(row,2).toString()+","+Attendance.getModel().getValueAt(row,3).toString()+""+Attendance.getModel().getValueAt(row,4).toString());
      pst.setString(2,jLabel3.getText());
      pst.setInt(4,1);
      pst.setInt(5,1);
      pst.setObject(6,Attendance.getModel().getValueAt(row,1).toString());

     String pres;
      if (()){
          pres="Absent";
      }  
      else{
          pres="Present";
      }
      pst.setString(3,pres);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in database as a `boolean` value using `JCheckBox#isSelected` method. For example:

```
boolean checkBoxSelected = table.getValueAt(row,0);
preparedStatement.setBoolean(columndId, checkBoxSelected);
```

Comment: I don't have a variable name for that checkbox. I just added it inside the jTable using Checkbox Wrapper.

Comment: @SydneyDelavin How would I know? You did not give any code to your question or even better a [mvce]. I Have edited my answer.

Comment: I updated my post and put the code that I used to add jCheckBox in my jTable.

Comment: @SydneyDelavin I do not understand what stops you to do what I'm trying to tell you. You have a boolean column into your database and a boolean value into your JTable. Just store it.

Comment: thank you for that sir. I fixed it with the method you told me to do.